# wtform locale does not work

Tags: flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms

I try to display form error in Japanese. This is my form def

```
class TwAccountUpdateForm(flask_wtf.FlaskForm):
  class Meta:
    locales = ('ja_JP', 'ja')

  text = wtforms.TextAreaField(u'キーワード',[wtforms.validators.required()],render_kw={"placeholder": u"キーワード1\nキーワード2\nキーワード3\n。。。"})
```

When I do not fill in the form, I get message 'This field is required'. 
It does not show Japanese text.
How to show japanese text?